# Custom destruction and deallocation of new'd object

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, rtti

Given a pointer obtained from a `new` expression, is it legal C++ to replace the corresponding `delete` expression with an explicit call to the destructor (or `std::destroy_at`) followed by a call to `operator delete`?

In my project I use a custom form of RTTI. For types with dynamically dispatched destructors the `delete` expression would not call the appropriate destructor but the destructor of the base class. To solve this issue, I 'manually' (through my RTTI machinery) call the correct destructor based on the runtime type of the allocated object, and than call `operator delete` directly to deallocate the memory.

This solution works well in my project (compiled with clang and msvc), but I wonder wether this invokes undefined behaviour.

**About `virtual`:**
I could of course archieve the dynamic dispatch of the destructor by making it `virtual`. This however gives the objects a vtable pointer, which is functionally not needed because I already have runtime type information in the object. So a `virtual` destructor solves the problem, but a) introduces unnecessary runtime overhead and more importantly b) it solves an already solved problem, so I would consider it a design flaw.

**Code example:**

With the dynamic dispatch mechanism provided by C++ the problem would be solved by a `virtual` destructor.

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base(); };
struct Derived: Base {
    // My data members which want to be properly destroyed 
};
// ...
Base* p = new Derived(/* ... */);
// ...
delete p; // Derived::~Derived() is being called.
```

However for several reasons I have a custom form of RTTI (which solves problems `virtual` functions can't solve).

```
struct Base { protected: int typeID = ID_OF_TYPE_BASE; };
struct Derived1: Base { 
    Base() { typeID = ID_OF_TYPE_DERIVED1; }
};
struct Derived2: Base { 
    Base() { typeID = ID_OF_TYPE_DERIVED2; }
};
```

Given a pointer `p` to `Base` I can dispatch functions based on the actual runtime type of `*p`, similar to `std::visit` on `std::variant`:

```
visit(p, [](auto* q) { 
    // Here *q is statically of the runtime type of *p, 
    // so either Base, Derived1 or Derived2.
});
```

This solves the same problems as the `virtual` keyword (except that class hierarchies are not easily extendable and it's not as pretty to write), so I can dispatch to the correct destructor like so:

```
visit(p, [](auto* q) { 
    std::destroy_at(q);
});
```

<strike>So I'm asking if the following is legal C++:</strike>

```
Base* p = new Derived1(/* ... */);
// ...
// delete p; // Calls Base::~Base() - potential memory leak because subobjects of *p are not destroyed. 
visit(p, [](auto* q) {
//  std::destroy_at(q); // Calls Derived1::~Derived1()
//  ::operator delete(q); // Deallocate through pointer to derived type
    // SOLUTION: Simply delete through pointer to derived type!
    delete q; 
});
```

*I'm not asking for advice wether using custom RTTI replacements is reasonable.*

I also don't want to imply that using raw `new` and `delete` is good practice, this is of course hidden behind `unique_ptr`'s.

The actual code:
https://github.com/chrysante/scatha/blob/main/lib/Common/UniquePtr.h

Comment: It's impossible to say, without representative code (preferably with comments or other documentation to explain what it does).  What are you trying to do that would not be achieved by the base class having a `virtual` destructor?

Comment: I edited the question and hope that clarifies it.

Comment: This cannot be legal, for obvious practical reasons. `Base` may not be located at offset zero within `Derived1`. So with `Base* p = new Derived1(/* ... */); ::operator delete(p);` what you are passing to `operator delete` may not be the same address as the one returned by `new`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for pointing that out. This can be solved however by passing the pointer to derived type to `operator delete`. I will edit the question.

Comment: You can remove all doubt if you construct in two steps, too. As in `void* raw = ::operator new(sizeof(Derived1)); Derived1* p = new(raw) Derived1; p->~Derived1(); ::operator delete(raw);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're right, and I actually just realised I can directly `delete` through the derived pointer, so that also solves the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ there is a (new) saying that every line of code can be found to have undefined behavior. Even things like "p++" can be UB. So being legal or not is quite a challenge in C++.

Now, does it work? If you are not doing anything out of the ordinary, it probably is, yes. I have been doing that for the past 15 years or so. I also do custom RTTI with memory pools and it works flawlessly.

Just for the sake of teaching, I wrote an example that uses intrusive pointers with custom delete on top of memory pools. You can [catch it on Github](https://github.com/HFTrader/hbthreads/blob/main/hbthreads/Pointer.h).

The only requirement that can come to my mind in general is that if your classes are polymorphic and you are deleting using a pointer to the base class, the base class has to be virtual.